# Cannot invoke 'Data.Type.init' with an argument list of type '([String])'

Tags: swift

I would like to init a data type with a sequence: init(S) but I get an error for following code:

```
let d = Data.init(["B","K"])
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? `Data`'s `init(_:)` takes a sequence of bytes, not strings.

Comment: The “proper”/easy way to convert a `string` to `Data` would be `string.data(using: .utf8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get an error because the generic `init` method has a type constraint. The sequence must be `[UInt8]`

```
public init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == UInt8
```

Just for fun, you can use

```
let bytes = ["B", "K"].joined().utf8.map{ UInt8($0) }
let d = Data(bytes)
```

Comment: UInt8 is not mentioned in documentation on the web. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2852972-init

Comment: @Adobels It's not great documentation, granted, but `Data.Element` is a type alias for `UInt8`.

Comment: I got this declaration from the header file (⌃⌘-click on `Data`)